# When saving entity converted from a DTO, hibernate throws TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance"

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, dto, modelmapper

First off - I know, it might seem like the same question has been asked a million times. However, this is related rather to DTOs, not entities nor missing cascades. If I create an entity myself and save it, everything is fine. The problem occurs when I create a DTO, convert it with ModelMapper and then try to save the converted entity. 
If you look at the test class, the first test(saveCarByEntity) passes but the second(saveCarByDto) one produces the error.
Every class connected can be seen below.
Thank you in advance.

**The entities**:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Car {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "car", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private CarDetails carDetails;
}
```

```
@Data
@Entity
public class CarDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "carDetails", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private Bumper bumper;

    @OneToOne
    private Car car;
}
```

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Bumper {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    private CarDetails carDetails;
}
```

**The DTO-s:**

```
@Data
public class CarDto {
    private Long id;
    private CarDetailsDto carDetails;
}
```

```
@Data
public class CarDetailsDto {
    private Long id;
    private BumperDto bumper;
    private CarDto car;
}
```

```
@Data
public class BumperDto {
    private Long id;
    private CarDetailsDto carDetails;
}
```

**The test class:**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
class CarTests {
    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @Autowired
    private CarRepository carRepository;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
    }

    @Test
    public void saveCarByEntity() {
        Car car = new Car();
        CarDetails carDetails = new CarDetails();
        Bumper bumper = new Bumper();

        car.setCarDetails(carDetails);
        carDetails.setCar(car);
        carDetails.setBumper(bumper);
        bumper.setCarDetails(carDetails);

        Car savedEntity = carRepository.save(car);
    }

    @Test
    public void saveCarByDto() {
        CarDto carDto = new CarDto();
        CarDetailsDto carDetails = new CarDetailsDto();
        BumperDto bumper = new BumperDto();

        carDto.setCarDetails(carDetails);
        carDetails.setCar(carDto);
        carDetails.setBumper(bumper);
        bumper.setCarDetails(carDetails);

        Car car = modelMapper.map(carDto, Car.class);

        Car savedEntity = carRepository.save(car);
    }
}
```

**Error produced:**

```
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.somepackage.model.Bumper.carDetails -> com.somepackage.model.CarDetails
```

**CarRepository:**

```
@Repository
public interface CarRepostiory extends JpaRepository<Car, Long> {
}
```

Comment: Could you provide code of `ModelMapper` and  `CarRepository` classes please?

Comment: Also try using `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` instead of  `PERSIST` and let me know how it goes

Comment: I've already tried using CascadeType.ALL instead of PERSIST but that had no effect.
As for the ModelMapper, I don't use a custom class. I just use the out of the package http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/
Added the CarRepostiory class above

Comment: Add `@JoinColumn(name = "car_id")` and `@JoinColumn(name = "carDetails_id")` to `CarDetails#car` and `Bumper#carDetails` respectively

Comment: I think your modelMapper breaks the child-parent relationship, seems like Bumper does not have reference to its parent "carDetails". From the error "transient instance" is the parent of Bumper and while orm tries to save child it sees unsaved parent(carDetails)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your model mapper does, but I bet if you persist car details without the bumper and then the bumper, it will work. Maybe you can make it work by using CascadeType.PERSIST in the Bumper for carDetails as well?

Comment: Adding CascadeType.PERSIST to both sidse of the relationship makes hibernate save both sides of the relationship twice so that will not work out.
If I were to persist car_details and bumper separately, I would have to remove the cascade part.

Comment: Persisting both objects twice sounds incorrect as that is handled in Hibernate through object identity. Maybe your object graph is wrong and your bumpers carDetails refers to a different carDetails object than the container?

Comment: That is something that has been on my mind all along. When I was running the test with debugger on, one interesting thing I found was that if I run the first test in which I create the entity from scratch and save it, CarDetails object has the same memory reference? in Car and Bumper classes. However, when I created the DTO, mapped it to an entity and then looked at the memory references, the reference was different in the Car and Bumper class. I guess my knowledge of how ModelMapper works is not good enough to understand whether the mistake might lie there or not.

Comment: How should the model mapper know that you want to refer to the same object? That's definitely the problem. You have to make sure you are referencing the same object after the model mapper did it's work.