# How to define unidirectional one to many dto in spring jpa

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, modelmapper

I've been trying for a few days to solve this issues but i can't seem to figure it out. I have 3 tables: Users, Employees(that extends Users) and Roles. The problem i have is that i can't seem to find a way to make hibernate understand that i want a one directional one to many between Users and Roles. I don't want to get all the Users from the Roles table side. With the bellow configuration, when i try to insert a new value in table Users, instead of using the existing values from Roles it inserts a new one making duplicate values with different id's. Do you have any suggestions? Thank you. Bellow are the classes i use:

User entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED) // used for the Employees table
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String username;
private String password;
private String e_mail;
private String phoneNumber;
private String name;
private String surname;
private Date birthDate;
private String adress;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
private Role role;

public User() { }

public User(String username, String password, String e_mail, String phoneNumber, String name,
            String surname, Date birthDate, String adress, Role role) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.e_mail = e_mail;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.birthDate = birthDate;
    this.adress = adress;
    this.role = role;
}

//getters and setters
}
```

Role entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

private String name;

public Role() { }

public Role(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

//getters and setters
}
```

UserDto:

```
public class UserDto {

@JsonIgnore
private Long id;
private String username;
private String password;
private String e_mail;
private String phoneNumber;
private String name;
private String surname;
private Date birthDate;
private String adress;
@JsonIgnore
private RoleDto role = new RoleDto();

public UserDto() { }

// getters and setters
}
```

RoleDto:

```
public class RoleDto {

@JsonIgnore
private Long id;
private String name;

public RoleDto() { }

// getters and setters
}
```

UserService:

```
@Service
public class UserService {

private UserRepository userRepository;
private ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();

public UserService(RoleService roleService, UserRepository userRepository, RoleRepository roleRepository) {
    this.roleService = roleService;
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
    this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
}

public void addUser(UserDto userDto) {
    userDto.setRole(roleService.getBuyerRoleDto());
    userRepository.save(modelMapper.map(userDto, User.class));
}

// other services...
}
```

RoleService:

```
@Service
public class RoleService {

private RoleRepository roleRepository;
private ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();

public RoleService(RoleRepository roleRepository) {
    this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
}

/*
* i've tested the queries getById and getBuyerId and they are working as they should
*/
public RoleDto getBuyerRoleDto() {
    return modelMapper.map(roleRepository.getbyId(roleRepository.getBuyerId()), RoleDto.class);
}

// other services...
}
```

Comment: Can you debug which `User` object you actually persist into DB?  You set @JsonIgnore on `id` fields, so they may be skipped by the modelMapper - so userDto has a roleDto without the id in `addUser `- that's why you try to persist User entity without Id containing a Role entity without id, thus creating a new Role.

Comment: I've removed the @JsonIgnore on all the Dtos fields and on the roleDto only and the result seems to be the same. At every User that i do insert, hibernate inserts a new row in the Roles table. It behaves like it is a one to one dependancy.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that your model mapper creates the Role instance by invoking the constructor. Such an object is "new" to JPA/Hibernate i.e. it's unmanaged.
To refer to an existing object, you need to use `entityManager.getReference(Role.class, roleId)` or `entityManager.find(Role.class, roleId)` and use that object in your User instance.

This is pretty similar to this issue: [When saving entity converted from a DTO, hibernate throws TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61301600/when-saving-entity-converted-from-a-dto-hibernate-throws-transientpropertyvalue/61306236?noredirect=1#comment108474146_61306236)

This model-mapping issue you are having is by the way the perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain/dto model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

Entity views can also be *updatable* and/or *creatable* i.e. support flushing changes back.

```
@CreatableEntityView
@EntityView(User.class)
public abstract class UserDto {
  @JsonIgnore
  Long getId();
  String getUsername();
  void setUsername(String username);
  String getPassword();
  void setPassword(String password);
  String getEmail();
  void setEmail(String email);
  String getPhoneNumber();
  void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber);
  String getName();
  void setName(String name);
  String getSurname();
  void setSurname(String surname);
  Date getBirthDate();
  void setBirthDate(Date birthDate);
  String getAdress();
  void setAdress(String adress);
  @JsonIgnore
  RoleDto getRole();
  void setRole(RoleDto role);
}
@EntityView(Role.class)
public interface RoleDto {
  @JsonIgnore
  Long getId();
  String getName();
}
```

Saving the new object is easy as Blaze-Persistence Entity Views will take care of mapping the object graph back to the entity/db model via JPA means for you.

`entityViewManager.save(entityManager, user);`

With the Spring Data and Spring Mvc integration, using DTOs is super easy and as fast as it can get. See an example application here: https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence/blob/master/examples/spring-data-webmvc/src/main/java/com/blazebit/persistence/examples/spring/data/webmvc/controller/CatRestController.java#L80

Answer (score 0):

You should provide attribute `@ManyToOne(optional = false)` so that this relationship become mandatory.

Comment: It still does the same thing inserting a new row in the Roles table

Answer (score 0):

Cascade Type is not required on Role.
Change below code from this ....

```java
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
private Role role;
```

....to this:

```java
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
private Role role;
```

Comment: If i remove the cascade i get : "org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation : com.example.project.model.User.role -> com.example.project.model.Role; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation : com.example.project.model.User.role -> com.example.project.model.Role"

Comment: I think one problem seems to be that instead of mapping to an existing model, it creates a new one